# How to get only public property using reflection in C# in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml

I am using

```
typeof(ClassName).GetRuntimeProperties()
```

This method will display all the properties. how will you get only public property from a class without binding flags, Any possible way please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties = 
    typeof(TClass)
        .GetRuntimeProperties()
        .Where( pi => pi.CanRead && pi.GetGetMethod().IsPublic );
```